# Rendering specific z x y tiles using Tilemill?

Tags: tilemill

I own a tilemill project executed in command line. I want to update an specific tiles in order to avoid to reload the entire mbtiles file. Too much CPU time.

I see in tilemill documentation the --scheme and --list params, but I don't know how it works.

Another user of this site  at [Rendering specific tiles (by x,y,z) using TileMill](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130223) posted a possible solution, but it does not work for me. I use a filescheme.json downloaded from github, and rewritten at my own tiles configuration, but it always returns 
[0s] 100.0000% 10/10 @ 32/s | 0s left | V 0 ■ 0 ? 10 fail 0
[0s] 100.0000% 10/10 @ 30/s | 0s left | V 0 ■ 0 ? 10 fail 0
and a empty mbtiles (16KB) file. No error thrown.

This is my filescheme.json

{"z":13,"x":3961,"y":5199,"key":false}
{"z":14,"x":7922,"y":10398,"key":false}
{"z":15,"x":15844,"y":20797,"key":false}
{"z":16,"x":31689,"y":41594,"key":false}
{"z":17,"x":63379,"y":83188,"key":false}
{"z":18,"x":126759,"y":166376,"key":false}
{"z":19,"x":253519,"y":332753,"key":false}
{"z":20,"x":507039,"y":665507,"key":false}
{"z":21,"x":1014079,"y":1331014,"key":false}
{"z":22,"x":2028158,"y":2662029,"key":false}

If it is not possible, is there any other possible solution to update a specific zxy tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a method. Using tilemill server to call via url the tiles individually.

TileMill is a web tileserver. Calling the internal URL, passing the ZXY URL returns the  image correctly.